# Jquery isn't having an effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My jquery isn't working. I suspect it's something to do with the `src` attribute I'm providing not being right. Both the html file and the js file reside in the same directory. I have tried this with `src` as the full path, like below, and with just the file name 'jquery1.js', and everything in between. Javascript is on in the browser(chrome) and my code works on jsfiddle. Can anyone see a problem here? What should my src attribute be when both files are in `"C:/code/html/jquery_tests"`?

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Google hosted libs -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- jquery -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/code/html/jquery_tests/jquery1.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div style="height:100px; width:40px"></div>
        <input id="name" type="text">
        <h2 id="greeting"></h2>
    </body>    
</html>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var name = $('#name');
    var greeting = $('#greeting');

    $("div").css("border", "3px solid red");

    name.keyup(function () {
        greeting.text('Hello ' + name.val() + '!');
    });

});
```

Comment: try `src="jquery1.js"` if both the html file and js file are in the same folder

Comment: What is the location of your html file ????

Comment: It can be a relative path to your HTML document

Comment: In your browser, see code font. Click in link scr jquery and if it opens the problem isn't it src

Comment: @Anton I tried this. It doesn't work.

Comment: try developer tool in chrome[f12] and check whether .js file available or not found.

Comment: try `<script type="text/javascript" src="file://C:/code/html/jquery_tests/jquery1.js"></script>`

Comment: The code is working properly, please be sure that the javascript files are located at mentioned location and loaded in html file properly.

Comment: @ArunPJohny This didn't work either

Comment: `<script src="//` - the double slash means that the reference to the file is protocol agnostic, so will work for `http:` and `https:`. Although it won't work if you just run the file directly, you need to install a web server for it to work (WAMP/LAMP/MAMP) stack.

Comment: @BhaveshGangani They are

Comment: Do you have any errors in Chrome developer tools (F12) under the Console tab or try the Network tab to see if the browser can locate the JS file.

Comment: @Dineshkumar I am getting the error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined' for line 1 of the script..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume your are working on a local machine and not online.
In this case, use http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
or https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js instead of "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" or link to a local copy of a jQuery version.

Your script is not downloading because the browser will default to the file:// protocol.

Comment: this did the job! I didn't know I had to include the 'http:' if working on my local machine. Now I know. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your html and jquery file is in the same location then just use the following code..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.js"></script>
```

And add the **http://** protocol in jquery loading like following..

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
```

Answer (score 1):

`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.js"></script>`

You should only need this if your HTML is in the same folder as the JavaScript file as your HTML file only knows the files in the same directory.

E.g. if your JS file was in a folder called JS, you would need to do:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery1.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

The source you are mentioning in the js file isn't correct as you are not providing the proper link to access the js file and that's why it's not downloading.Therefore include either of the versions as you like.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

OR

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ohh thanks a lot for telling that, I wasn't knowing. @AnttiHaapala